# R code + "rethinking" package: Bad binding access

Tags: r, stan, rstan

I try to reproduce an example from the book written by Richard McElreath: "Statistical rethinking", and get the error "**Bad binding access**". Here the code:

```
## Generate fake data for example 6.2: 
set.seed(909)
nSim      = 100
height    = rnorm(nSim,10,2)
leg_prop  = runif(nSim,0.4,0.5) 
leg_left  = leg_prop*height + rnorm( nSim , 0 , 0.02 )
leg_right = leg_prop*height + rnorm( nSim , 0 , 0.02 )
df        = data.frame(height, leg_left, leg_right)

## Fit data:
library(rethinking)
MAP = quap(
  alist(
    height ~ dnorm( mu , sigma ) ,
    mu <- a + bl*leg_left + br*leg_right ,
    a  ~ dnorm( 10 , 100 ) ,
    bl ~ dnorm( 2 , 10 ) ,
    br ~ dnorm( 2 , 10 ) ,
    sigma ~ dexp( 1 )
  ),
  data=df )
```

If I replace "quap" by "ulam", the code runs without errors. Therefore, I believe this is a problem between my R version and the rethinking package.

Here my versions:

- R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31) -- "Innocent and Trusting"
- Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit) M1 processor
- OSX "Monterey" 12.5.1
- CmdStan version: 2.31.0
- rethinking version: 2.21
- rstan version: 2.21.8

Comment: I get no error using Version: 2.31. You seem to be using a out-of-date version of pkg:rethinking.